# Getting size of List is zero in Parse Android

Tags: android, back4app

I try to read the list of Noodle And Sauce from the Back4app server.
I check in log cat it is returning my list size to zero.
But I have one Item in Back4app.
Please check where is the problem.
This is my NoodlesAndSauce class on Back4App
[image]

This is My Model Class

```
package com.piyushjaiswal121.demo;

import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

@ParseClassName("NoodlesAndSauce")
public class NoodlesAndSauce extends ParseObject {


    public NoodlesAndSauce() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return getString("Name");
    }

    public Number getQuantity() {
        return getInt("Quantity");
    }

    public Number getPrice() {
        return getInt("price");
    }

    public boolean isInStock() {
        return getBoolean("inStock");
    }

    public ParseFile getImage() {
        return getParseFile("image");
    }






}
```

This is My Fragment Code where I am querying

```
private void Fetch()
    {
        ParseQuery<NoodlesAndSauce> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(NoodlesAndSauce.class);

        parseQuery.setLimit(100);
       parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<NoodlesAndSauce>() {
           @Override
           public void done(List<NoodlesAndSauce> objects, ParseException e) {
               if(e==null)
               {
                   Log.d("Checking size",String.valueOf(objects.size()));
                   list.addAll(objects);
                   recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
               else
               {
                Log.d("Error in Fetch Noodles", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
               }
           }
       });

This is where I register and also added in Manifest
public class ParseInitialize extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Add your initialization code here
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(NoodlesAndSauce.class);


        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();


        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please remove the constructor of your custom subclass and try again?

Comment: Constructor are necessary!!

Comment: Could you please share the ACL in place for this object that you have in this class?